# Get all current values in a collection when defining its simples chema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

So I have a semantic type collection here to define my type. It has a field `arrayValue`. The functionality is the new semantic type here can be an array of existing semantic types, either predefined or defined by the user. The problem is that all the semantic types are stored in the collection itself. So is it possible to get the values in collection (something like SemanticTypes.findOne().semanticType) when defined the schema? Here's the code:
collection:

```
SemanticTypes = new Meteor.Collection('semanticTypes');
Schemas.SemanticTypes = new SimpleSchema({
   semanticType: {
      type: String,
      regEx: /^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/,
      unique: true
    },
    baseType:{
      type: String,
      autoform: {
        options: [
          {label: "int", value: "int"},
          {label: "float", value: "float"},
          {label: "string", value: "string"},
          {label: "bool", value: "bool"},
          {label: "array", value: "array"}
         ]
        }
       },
       arrayValue: {
          type: String,
          optional: true,
          autoform: {
             options: 
              // I want to get all current semantic types in the collection now
          }
        }
});
SemanticTypes.attachSchema(Schemas.SemanticTypes);
```

html:

```
<template name="addSemanticTypeForm">
 {{#autoForm collection="SemanticTypes" id="insertSemanticTypeForm" type="insert"}}
     <fieldset>
         {{> afQuickField name='semanticType'}}
         {{> afQuickField name='baseType' }}
         {{#if isArraySelected}}
             {{> afQuickField name='arrayValue'}}
         {{/if}}
     </fieldset>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
 {{/autoForm}}
 </template>
```

js:

```
Template.addSemanticTypeForm.onCreated(function() {
    Session.set("isArraySelected", false);
});

Template.addSemanticTypeForm.helpers({
  isArraySelected: function() {
    return Session.get("isArraySelected");
   }
});

Template.addSemanticTypeForm.events({
   'change select[name=baseType]': function(evt) {
      if ($(evt.currentTarget).val() == "array"){
          Session.set("isArraySelected", true);
       }
     else {
         Session.set("isArraySelected", false);
       }
    }
   });
```

Comment: I don't believe you want to put all the distinct values of `semanticType` into an array that is itself in the schema. Are you trying to create a menu in autoform?

Comment: yes. My logic here is that there's an option to create an array of existing semantic types. So when one selects "array", it'll pop up a new autoform option menu to let me choose from the existing semantic types

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to do it by defining an options variable in the helper to get all values in the collection with `collection.find()`, and use `{{> afQuickField name="arrayType" options=arrayOptions}}` in html. Here's my code:

js:

```
Template.addSemanticTypeForm.onCreated(function() {
Session.set("isArraySelected", false);
});

Template.addSemanticTypeForm.helpers({
   isArraySelected: function() {
   return Session.get("isArraySelected");
   },
   arrayOptions: function(){
      var options = [];
      SemanticTypes.find().forEach(function(type){
         options.push({label: type.semanticType, value: type.semanticType});
      });  
      return options;
     }
});

 Template.addSemanticTypeForm.events({
   'change select[name=baseType]': function(evt) {
    if ($(evt.currentTarget).val() == "array"){
       Session.set("isArraySelected", true);
     }
   else {
     Session.set("isArraySelected", false);
   }
  }
 });
```

html:

```
<template name="addSemanticTypeForm">
  {{#autoForm collection="SemanticTypes" id="insertSemanticTypeForm" type="insert"}}
   <fieldset>
       {{> afQuickField name='semanticType'}}
       {{> afQuickField name='baseType' }}
       {{#if isArraySelected}}
           {{> afQuickField name='arrayValue' options=arrayOptions}}
       {{/if}}
  </fieldset>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
{{/autoForm}}
</template>
```